# How to classify eBay sales and PayPal income on GNUcash properly?

Tags: gnucash, paypal, ebay

I tried to figure this out but can't seem to do it. Here's my thinking:

```
income:eBay - €10 from eBay (true)
```

Then this money goes to:

```
bank:PayPal €9.75  
expenses:PayPal fees €0.25
```

Then the PayPal account shows as if it only receives €9.75, but in reality it receives €10 and then it takes away €0.25 FROM the PayPal account as fees.

Alternative I tried:

```
bank:PayPal €10
```

goes to in two separate transactions (which makes it look really messy):

```
income:eBay €9.75  
expenses:PayPal fees €0.25
```

This option makes it look messy but it works properly.

Is there a way to do it using a split transaction (or another option that makes it look less messy, no double transactions), in which it is actually as it appears on my PayPal - which is, PayPal gets €10, then it takes away €0.25 as fees, and therefore the income from eBay is €9.75?

Comment: What's the problem with the one you're suggesting (10 credit to income, 9.75 and 0.25 debits to asset and expense)?

Comment: What about making it *four* lines: 10 income, 10 paypal, 0.25 paypal, 0.25 fees?

Comment: Your first attempt was correct, as confirmed by the answer below.  The problem lies with a statement you make in the question: "Then the PayPal account shows as if it only receives €9.75" - this is incorrect.  The PayPal account shows a *balance* of 9.75, after receiving 10.00 and deducting 0.25 for fees.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I am just beginning to learn gnucash but I am also just beginning to understand double-entry accounting. (This was occasioned by my having been asked asked to be the treasurer of a non-profit organization I belong to.) So please make sure you double-check my answer below with someone more knowledgable.

You cannot consider €9.75 to be Income and €0.25 to be Expenses:Fees, because for reporting and equity purposes, Net Income will be computed as Income – Fees, which would come out to €9.50, whereas it should come out to €9.75. Since Net Income will be used to compute taxes at some time in the future, you will be under-reporting Net Income and therefore underpaying your taxes. both of which are bad for business, albeit in different ways.

So I'd do a split transaction something like this:

```
Income:Sales increases by €10.00 (Credit)
Expenses:Fees increases by €0.25 (Debit)
Assets:PayPal:Cash increases by $9.75 (Debit)
```

Of course, I don't know exactly how you break down your accounts, so you might have different names for some of the subaccounts.

By the way, I've found the official Gnucash.org "gnucash-users" mailing list to be extremely helpful. [This link](https://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Mailing_Lists#At_gnucash.org) gives instructions for joining. You can then get much more expert responses on both Gnucash issues and accounting issues by posting your query there.

I hope the above is helpful.